# How can I speed up this JavaScript painting app?

Tags: java, javascript, html, flash, canvas

Alright, I've built a paint app that includes a paint bucket tool using HTML canvas.  The problem with the paint bucket is that, even though I made it as efficient as possible, it takes a long time to respond.  Is this a problem of the browser not being given enough processing power?  Is Javascript just slow?  Is canvas just slow?

Would Java be the best alternative for processor-intensive functions like this?  Or maybe flash?

Alright, here's some code.  The top part (before the line break) runs, and then the part below the line break runs four times, one for each direction from the cursor. (left, up, right, down)  The one showing is for one pixel to the left obviously.

```
if (typeof paintPos[x] === 'undefined') {
    paintPos[x] = {};
}
paintPos[x][y] = x+'|'+y;

var runRecurse = 0;
if (typeof paintPos[x-1] === 'undefined') {
    runRecurse = 1;
} else if (typeof paintPos[x-1][y] === 'undefined') {
    runRecurse = 1;
}
if (runRecurse === 1) {
    if (x-1 >= 0) {
        var colData = ctx.getImageData(x-1, y, 1, 1).data;
        var colHexNew = "#" + ("000000" + 
            rgbToHex(colData[0],colData[1],colData[2])).slice(-6);
        if (colHex === colHexNew) {
            setPaintPos(x-1,y,colHex);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to actually paint in, I just do this:

```
$.each(paintPos,function(key,value) {
    $.each(paintPos[key],function(key2,value2) {
        var paintCol = value2.split('|');
        var paintX = paintCol[0];
        var paintY = paintCol[1];
        ctx.fillRect(paintX,paintY,1,1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Answer: Maybe.  Show us your code.

Comment: Without code your question was way too subjective and likely to lead to debate. Now it's a lot better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing pixel-level manipulations. Drawing tiny 1-pixel rectangles is likely not the most efficient way of doing that.

The HTML5 Canvas provides access to the pixels of your canvas through the [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#getImageData%28%29) function. This function returns the byte[] buffer with pixels data (4 bytes per pixel, in rgba format) of a region of your canvas.

You can then cheaply manipulate the pixels in that byte[].

After building up you picture, you can draw the data back into the canvas with [`putImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#putImageData%28%29).

This tutorial seems pretty good: http://creativejs.com/2011/12/day-3-play-with-your-pixels/

Answer (score 0):

Without more specifics it is impossible to say whether the problem is processing power. You could be running into system limitations, or your code could just contain one of many possible inefficiencies.

Generally speaking though, processor-load is processor-load. So rewriting the Javascript-code into Java wouldn't speed up your application in itself.

What you would be able to do using Java (and other programming languages) is use multi-threaded code, which will allow your application to execute different parts of code at the same time using different processor cores when possible.

Using multiple threads you would be able to keep your application responsive, whilst it is performing heavy processing/calculations.

Javascript really isn't prepared for heavy applications like the one you apparently developed. For one, many browsers will ask users if they want to disable Javascript when your code takes more than a few seconds to execute.